# Automating a dropdown in amazon

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

Actually, I am trying to automate the Amazon website, where I have to select a category from the dropdown, as shown in the snapshot. But when I try to do so, it says `ElementNotInteractableException`.

[image]

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nav-search-scope nav-sprite']"));
dropDown.click();
// Scroll the dropdown element into view using JavaScript
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", dropDown);

// Wait for the dropdown to be clickable and visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropDown));


//selecting dropdown
Select select = new Select(dropDown);
select.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the correct error based on the code you provided. The correct error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"
```

and the reason for this is `Select()` expects a SELECT element but your locator returns a DIV. You can easily fix this by changing the locator to point at the SELECT element using the ID,

```
By.id("searchDropdownBox")
```

You also have a lot of unnecessary code. Your code basically reads like

1. Find the dropdown and click it - unnecessary because of step 4, below
2. Scroll to the dropdown - you've already clicked it so this step is unnecessary
3. Wait until the dropdown is clickable - again, you've already clicked it so this step is unnecessary
4. Convert the dropdown to a `Select` element and select the first item in the dropdown

Your entire code can be reduced to just

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

Find the SELECT element by ID (simple and resilient locator), convert it to a `Select` so that it's easier to work with, and then select the desired OPTION using an index.